# Using bs4 to extract section using text, without tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, data-extraction

For an assignment I have a financial report that does not have tags except for tables.
I need to extract texts from certain section.
For. e.g. one section is titled "Management's Discussion and Analysis".
The only tag at the start of the page is `<page>` which ends at the end of the document instead of the actual page.
How can I extract the entire "Management's Discussion and Analysis" section using just the string title. It has multiple section inside of it and has no tags to know where it ends. Just an index and text/heading with the other section beginning.
.
.
.Just to give a snapshot of how the page is laid out:

```
<page>
MANAGEMENTS DISCUSSION AND ANALYSIS
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum nec augue dolor. Aliquam erat volutpat. 
Aliquam vel leo venenatis, commodo nisi in, lacinia ligula. Fusce non placerat quam, ac viverra diam. Suspendisse potenti. 
Vestibulum sit amet bibendum ipsum. Vivamus placerat feugiat justo, vel rhoncus enim sagittis non. Integer id iaculis lorem. 

OVERVIEW
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum nec augue dolor. Aliquam erat volutpat. 
Aliquam vel leo venenatis, commodo nisi in, lacinia ligula. Fusce non placerat quam, ac viverra diam. Suspendisse potenti. 
Vestibulum sit amet bibendum ipsum. Vivamus placerat feugiat justo, vel rhoncus enim sagittis non. Integer id iaculis lorem. 

<page>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum nec augue dolor. Aliquam erat volutpat. 
Aliquam vel leo venenatis, commodo nisi in, lacinia ligula. Fusce non placerat quam, ac viverra diam. Suspendisse potenti. 
Vestibulum sit amet bibendum ipsum. Vivamus placerat feugiat justo, vel rhoncus enim sagittis non. Integer id iaculis lorem. 

FOREIGN AFFAIRS:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum nec augue dolor. Aliquam erat volutpat. 
Aliquam vel leo venenatis, commodo nisi in, lacinia ligula. Fusce non placerat quam, ac viverra diam. Suspendisse potenti. 
Vestibulum sit amet bibendum ipsum. Vivamus placerat feugiat justo, vel rhoncus enim sagittis non. Integer id iaculis lorem.
```

I want to extract all the text from "Management's Discussion and Analysis" to "Foreign Affairs".

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing much i guess you can do with bs4 in this case. You will have to use regex to match a line Which is completely in uppercase and then take the substring between that complete caps line and a emply blank line.

This code returns all the lines which are completly in uppercase.

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r"^([A-Z ':]+$)", re.M)

UPPERCASE = [line for line in string.split("\n") if rx.match(line)]
print(UPPERCASE)
```

where string is your test string.